# execute node with php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I want to execute a javascript file with **node (node.js)** without using windows terminal, so I am trying to use php's **exec()** function to execute the file, but it isn't working.

What is the problem ? Did I write the wrong windows command? Did I write the wrong full path of node (I wrote it but maybe it's a backslash problem)? Windows doesn't know the "node" command?

```js
console.log('Welcome to Node.js !');
```

```html
<?php
echo exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe welcometonode.js');//not working
echo exec('node welcometonode.js');//not working
echo exec('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe welcometonode.js');//not working
echo exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node welcometonode.js');//not working



?>
```

Comment: does `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe welcometonode.js'` work on ur cmd? also try full path of `welcometonode.js`

Comment: Did you try before running the command from normal terminal, right? As Iceman says..

Comment: nope, if i write "nope welcometonode.js" on cmd, it works, but it is not working on exec() so i changed the command prompt :/

Comment: can anyone vote at least ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the windows terminal? The terminal really is the normal place to launch many types of application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not work well with spaces as you need to tell it it's all part of the same command, you will need to enclose the full command path within double quotes (singles don't work), then replace your backward slashes for forward slashes, is always better to use forward within your scripts, also, provide the full path to the node script as well, else it will assume the script exists on whatever directory your php script or php binary itself is running, so is better to avoid confusions, this would work:

```
exec("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node.exe\" \"C:/path/to/script/welcometonode.js\"");
```

Comment: it's working sir, thank you for information, thank you so much !